# How can I ensure a user field is hidden by default for the logged in user?

Tags: entities, users

Module X provides a field-definition and attaches it to the user-entity.

Attaching metadata to the user in that way makes for a very convenient way to access it across the site.

However, by default, a logged in user will also be able to both view and edit this data, which is not always desirable.

Is there a way for the same module to ensure that this field is hidden by default?

Comment: I've posted a potential solution myself, but I'm not really happy with it. I wish there was a simpler solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to depend from a module implemented by others, you can implement [hook_field_access()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_access/7) in your own module. It is quite easy to change the access permission for an entity field, knowing its name.

```
function mymodule_field_access($op, $field, $entity_type, $entity, $account) {
  if ($field['field_name'] == 'field_of_interest' && $op == 'edit') {
    return user_access('edit field of interest', $account);
  }
  return TRUE;
}
```

`$op` is `'edit'`, or `view'`; `$entity` contains the object for the entity to which the field is attached; `$entity_type` is the entity type.

With a module that aims the specific fields for which you want to control the access, it is easy to enable the access control: Just enable the module when you need it, and disable it when the access control is not necessary.

Comment: Perfect! How could I have missed this function?

Comment: It is not that easy to find. I know about it because I followed (for a short time) the development of Drupal 7 from the Drupal.org project queue. `:)`

Answer (score 0):

1. Depend on [field_permission](http://drupal.org/project/field_permission).
2. Export permissions for the field.
3. Set the permissions to FALSE on hook_install.